# A sort of weak nullstellensatz for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Be $S$ a finite set of square matrices $A_i$ of order $n$ with entries in $\mathbb C$, such that the null vector is the only element in the intersection of their kernels: $$\cap_i ker(A_i)=\{0\}$$
Does the left ideal generated by $S$ coincide with the unit ideal of $M_n(\mathbb C)$?

Comment: It's not true in general: take $S$ to contain only one element, $A$, which is a matrix of full rank that is not a scalar multiple of the identity. Then $ker(A) = \{0\}$, but $A$ does not generate the unit ideal.

Comment: If a matrix $A$ is of full rank then exist $B$ and $C$ such that $$BAC=1$$ So $A$ does generates the unit ideal. Where am i wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I got slightly confused as to in what sense it was generating it.

Comment: I think the answer is that, as long as we deal with two-sided ideals intersection of kernels doesn't matter and the condition for generating the unit ideal is that the sum of ranks is at least $n$. My wonder now is about one-sided ideals..

Comment: You need some kind of "general position" type hypothesis in there (else take $n$ scalar multiples of a matrix of rank 1).

Comment: You are right, with two sided ideals a single matrix of rank one generates all the matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true, and works over any field $k$.  Let $I\subseteq M_n(k)$ be a left ideal.  Since $M_n(k)$ is a semisimple ring, there is another left ideal $J\subseteq M_n(k)$ such that $I\oplus J=M_n(k)$.  Let $i\in I$ and $j\in J$ be such that $i+j=1$.  Then for any $i'\in I$, $i'j=i'(1-i)\in I\cap J=0$, so $i'=i'i$.  In particular, $\ker(i)\subseteq \ker(i')$ for all $i'\in I$.

Now in your case that $I$ is generated by matrices whose kernels have trivial intersection, this means that $\ker(i)$ must be trivial.  Thus $i$ is invertible, so $I=M_n(k)$ since $i\in I$.

(More generally, we can conclude that every left ideal in $M_n(k)$ the set of matrices that vanish on some subspace of $k^n$, namely the kernel of $i$.)